# Calculate the partial vapor pressures of a variable at xB = 0.75 based on the interpolation functions of the data

Tags: plotting, interpolation, homework, chemistry

I'm having troubles in solving an exercise for an assignment in my Chemistry course. Talking about interpolations, I've already have a graph but I need to calculate the partial vapor pressures of benzene and 2-propanol as well as the total vapor pressure at xB = 0.75 based on the interpolation functions of the data.

```
xB = {0.00, 0.076, 0.164, 0.300, 0.479, 0.638, 0.854, 0.941, 1.00}; 
pP = {44.0, 42.2, 39.5, 36.4, 30.4, 27.6, 22.4, 12.9, 0.00}; 
pT = {44.0, 66.4, 84.0, 99.8, 105.8, 108.4, 109.0, 104.5, 94.4};
```

Graph are plotted with coordinates of $(xB,pP)$ and $(xB,pT)$.

Comment: Have you tried reading this https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html and related help files?

Comment: I don't know how to relate the data to each function. I just don't find what would fit my case anywhere, could you be more specific?
Thank you for the quick answer, I'm grateful

Answer (score 3):

```
xB = {0.00, 0.076, 0.164, 0.300, 0.479, 0.638, 0.854, 0.941, 1.00}; 
pP = {44.0, 42.2, 39.5, 36.4, 30.4, 27.6, 22.4, 12.9, 0.00}; 
pT = {44.0, 66.4, 84.0, 99.8, 105.8, 108.4, 109.0, 104.5, 94.4};

iP = Interpolation[{xB, pP}\[Transpose]];
iT = Interpolation[{xB, pT}\[Transpose]];

Show[
 Plot[{iP[x], iT[x]}, {x, Min[xB], Max[xB]}],
 ListPlot[{{xB, pP}\[Transpose], {xB, pT}\[Transpose]}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{iP[0.75], iT[0.75]}
(* {25.2953, 106.883} *)
```

Comment: Adding `Method -> "Spline"` to the `Interpolation`s provides a better interpolation in this case - no visual artifact between `0.6` and `0.8`.